# can't build python program from .py to .exe using PyInstaller library

Tags: python, pyinstaller

error translation ("pip" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file.)
why can't I get the library installed? please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Juk.png)

I tried to add the path to python in Path but why do i get another window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2bbm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't have pip installed. You can [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) in a Python environment with the following command

Linux / macOS:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Windows:

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Alternativly you can Download get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run on Windows:

```
py get-pip.py
```

Or on Linux / macOS:

```
python get-pip.py
```